# Controlling repainting of elements in animated SVG

Tags: css, animation, svg, repaint, velocity.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to control repainting of animated elements within an SVG which is embedded in the page via an `<object>` tag.

When I use an inline SVG and inspect repainting (using Chrome's "show repaint rectangles"), I can see that only the animated element within the SVG is being repainted. However, when the same SVG is included as an `<object>`, the animated element seems to cause the entire image to repaint continuously.

I've tried animating both with velocity.js and with CSS animation (keyframes + styles embedded in the SVG itself). With the latter, when I view the SVG on its own, only the animated element repaints, but when it's embedded in an `<object>` the whole thing repaints.

This seems inefficient, and I'd like to fix it, but I can't seem to find any information on why this is happening or how to prevent it. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Presumably it's some internal Chrome inefficiency. You'd probably have to download and build Chrome from source, identify and fix the issue in the Chrome code and submit a patch to fix it.

Comment: Yikes, I guess you could be right. Fixing Chrome itself is likely to be beyond my ability though, unfortunately.

Comment: As far as the browser is concerned, it's a single image that's being drawn - the drawing is going through and rendering it etc - which means that having it as an inline svg is far better for animation (and better supported in V2 beta). This is one of these things that is purely up to the browser vendors to fix sadly - if you can keep it inline then do!

Answer (score 0):

add `will-change: transform;` css rule to the object (or img tag)

> The will-change property allows you to inform the browser ahead of time of what kinds of changes you are likely to make to an element, so that it can set up the appropriate optimizations before they’re needed...

[more info](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)

```css
img, object {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/animate/anim01.svg" />
<object data="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/animate/anim01.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

**IMPORTANT:** this `img, object` css rule only for this example DON'T use it in production. Using it put all your images into separate layers. Its will eat up the browsers memory and the performance gonna be worst

Comment: While I loved the idea of this flag, it's actually worse than useless - the current browser implementations actually result in worse performance or quality than not using it at all.

Comment: @Rycochet Interesting I have a really good experience with that. Based on the Performance monitor in chrome (way shorter paint task, but a little bit longer composite layers task), of course depends how complex is the document.

Comment: Unless it's been recently changed - the drawing can be pushed onto the GPU, which results in a loss of quality that's pretty obvious, there's other issues with it too. Here's a useful writeup from the guys at GSAP (yes, it's a competitor, but it does things differently so that's not an issue) - https://greensock.com/will-change

Comment: @Rycochet I checked the link looks like they fixed these issues in new version of chrome.